# Проверка попадание точки в штриховку

Tags: lisp, autocad

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

радиус кругов = 100
длинна сторон квадрата = 400

нужно проверить попадает ли точка в круг: если да то точка в круге, если нет то точка в квадрате

пример моего кода:

```
(print "Do you get a point in the square?")
```

(cond (<= 400 x -400) && (<= 400 y -400)
 (print "Yes! Point in the square")
     (print"No! Point")
  (getpoint))

Answer (score 1):

Вам понадобится функция, которая проверяет, лежит ли точка с указанными координатами внутри окружности. Я предлагаю использовать такую её реализацию:

```
(defun isPointInsideCircle (x y xc yc r)
    (< (+ (* (- x xc) (- x xc)) (* (- y yc) (- y yc))) (* r r)))
```

Кроме этого, Вам нужно проверять, что точка лежит внутри квадрата. Сделать Вы это можете с помощью данной функции:

```
(defun isInsideRectangle (x y xc yc w h)
    (and (< (- x xc) w) (< (- y yc) h)))
```

В итоге получается, что точка лежит в заштрихованной части фигуры, если она не выходит за пределы квадрата и не находится ни в одной из окружностей. Объедим это все эти условия вот так:

```
(defun isInsideArea (x y)
    (let ((w 400)
          (h 400)
          (r 100)
          (xc1 100)
          (yc1 200)
          (xc2 300)
          (yc2 200))
        (and (isInsideRectangle x y 0 0 w h) 
             (not (isPointInsideCircle x y xc1 yc1 r)) 
             (not (isPointInsideCircle x y xc2 yc2 r)))))
```

Пример использования `isInsideArea`:

```
(cond ((isInsideArea 100 399) "The point is inside the area") (t "The point is not inside the area"))
```